# Product ID in firebase does not get created

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am missing something and can't figure out what it is. I am creating a shopping cart service and for some reason, when a user adds an additional product of a different kind to the cart, the cart gets overwritten with the new product and not creating a new product id to hold the new product. Can any body tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

My ShoppingCart Service

```
export class ShoppingCartService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  private create() {
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime()
    });
  }

  private getCart(cartId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId);
  }

  getItem(cartId: string, productId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);

  }

  private async getOrCreateCartId() {
    const cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId');
    if (cartId) { return cartId; }

    const result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId', result.key);
    return result.key;

  }

  async addToCart(product: Product) {
    const cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    const item$ = this.getItem(cartId, product.key);
    item$.snapshotChanges().take(1).subscribe(item => {
      if (item.payload.exists()) {
        item$.update({ product: product, quantity: item.payload.val().quantity + 1});
      } else {
          item$.update({ product: {
            title: product.title,
            price: product.price,
            category: product.category,
            imageUrl: product.imageUrl,

          }, quantity: 1} );
        }
    });

  }

}
```

My product model

```
export interface Product {
    key: string;
    title: string;
    price: number;
    category: string;
    imageUrl: string;

}
```

And this is a screenshot from firebase
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can to create a new 'ID' before save data:

```
const beforeId = this.db.createId();
```

and can create a ref using this new id:

```
const ref = this.db.collection('item').doc(beforeId );
```

Now you can add your data:

```
   ref.set({
    key: 'yourkey';
    title: 'yourTitle';
 ...
     })
        .then(function (docRef) {
         console.log('Save success!', docRef);
        })
        .then(response => {
          console.error('response: ', response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.error('Error: ', error);
        });
```